Lotusscript erase array
I need to clean an array used in a loop. However, after the erasing it, the array is not empty.
Dim arr As Variant
Print IsEmpty(arr)  ' true
ReDim arr(1) As String
arr(0)="Test"
arr(1)="Test2"
Erase arr
Print IsEmpty(arr)  'false`

How can I check whether array is empty after erasing?
Testing ubound(arr(0)) gave an lotusscript error.

Erase deletes array completely and variable arr is uninitialized afterwards (no dimension): Erase statement - Dynamic array = "The array retains its type, but has no elements.".
Use ReDim arr(1) As String without "preserve" instead: ReDim statement. It creates a new array of given dimension with empty entries:
Dim arr As Variant
ReDim arr(1) As String
arr(0)="Test"
arr(1)="Test2"
Print "arr(0): " + arr(0) ' arr(0): Test

ReDim arr(1) As String
Print "arr(0): " + arr(0) ' arr(0):
Print UBound(arr)         ' 1

Erase arr
Print UBound(arr)         ' Error: Attempt to access uninitialized dynamic array


There's also the function IsArray in LotusScript, if you want to assure yourself about the type "inside" a Variant.
